# cin doesn't work along with freopen in wsl windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cin, wsl-2, freopen

I am running this simple cpp code in wsl and it outputs infinite times.

The reason being when I take input into the variable `t`, it simply doesn't take, and it still has the garbage value initiated to it.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n;
}

int32_t main() {
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using WSL on VSCode.

Input:

> 2 1 0

Output:

[image: output screenshot]

The `cin` works fine with normal console input, but doesn't work with `freopen()`.

Why is this happening? Is this a problem with the `freopen()` function? Or is there something wrong in my WSL installation?

Comment: The `FILE*` `stdin` has nothing at all to do with the `std::istream` `std::cin` other than the fact that they both initially reference the same input device.

Comment: @MilesBudnek that is not true. By default, the [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) and [`stdin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/std_streams) streams are linked together. You have to explicitly unlink them with [`stdd::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Comment: @ParthivReddy You are not validating that cin >> t is successful before using t. Always check the stream state after reading input, eg: `if (cin >> t) { /* use t as needed */ } else { /* error */ }`

Comment: I think I found the mistake. The pwd had no file "input.txt". It actually had one but pwd got changed i dunno why. hence it was giving the error. Thanks for helping btw.